# How to get average number of observations per group?

Tags: stata

In my dataset, I have observations for football matches. One of my variables is `hometeam`. Now I want to get the average amount of observations per `hometeam`. How do I do that in Stata?

I know that I could `tab hometeam`, but since there are over 500 distinct hometeams, I don't want to do the calculation manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bysort hometeam : gen n = _N 
bysort hometeam : gen tag = _n == 1 
su n if tag
```

EDIT Another way to do it more concisely

```
bysort hometown : gen n = _N if _n == 1 
su n
```

Why the tagging then? It is often useful to have a tag variable when you are moving back and forth between individual and group level. `egen, tag()` does the same thing.

Why `if _n == 1`? You need to have this value just once for each group, and there are two ways of doing it that always work for groups that could be as small as one observation, to do it for the first or the last observation in a group. In a group of 1, they are the same, but that doesn't matter. So `if _n == _N` is another way to do it.

```
bysort hometown : gen n = _N if _n == _N
```

The code needs to be changed in situations where you need not to count missings on some variable

```
bysort hometown : gen n = sum(!missing(myvar)) 
by hometown : replace n = . if _n < _N
```

`egen, count()` is similar, but not identical.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can identify the different `hometeam`s with some `id` variable.

If you want the average number of observations per `id` this is one way:

```
clear all
set more off

input id hometeam
1 .
1 5
1 0
3 6
3 2
3 1
3 9
2 7
2 7
end

list, sepby(id)

bysort id: egen c = count(hometeam)
by id: keep if _n == 1
summarize c, meanonly
disp r(mean)
```

Note that observations with missings are not counted by `count`. If you did want to count the missings, then you could do:

```
bysort id: gen c = _n
by id: keep if _n == _N
summarize c, meanonly
disp r(mean)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. However, I think it would be nice to have some solution which does not require deleting observations.

Comment: You are welcome. @NickCox gives an answer to this. His `hometeam` variable is my `id`. Basically, instead of using `keep`, `generate` a `tag` variable with which you can condition the `summarize`.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2: Using the data of @Roberto

```
   collapse (count) hometeam, by(id)
    sum hometeam,meanonly
```